# Should we merge 'water vessel design' and 'shipbuilding'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

The phrase ['water-vessel-design'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-vessel-design) ([water-vessel-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-vessel-design)) is really wordy; something like 'ship-design' would be a little better. However, we do have the tag [shipbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipbuilding) ([shipbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipbuilding)), which is

1. An actual term
2. Concise

The two also seem to be similar in usage; there are four questions using both of these tags and one uses both.

Should we combine the two? I'd suggest one as a synonym of the other but I lack the necessary in rep in either tag. I'd also like to hear a discussion on this.

---

Note: [shipbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipbuilding) can apparently also be used for spaceships, so my preference would be to get rid of the [water-vessel-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-vessel-design) tag by making it a synonym of [shipbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipbuilding), and use [shipbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shipbuilding) instead.

Comment: I suggested water-vessel-design as a synonym of shipbuilding.

Comment: Somebody please check to make sure we're clearly distinguishing, in tagging, spaceships and water ships?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I checked, and it appears everything's fine.

Comment: Good.  Thanks for checking!

Comment: It's been marked as a synonym. Do you want to self-answer this as marked, or do you want to change this to [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @FoxElemental Good point. I've marked this as [tag:status-completed].